# MyPy checking typing.Protocol with Python 3.7 Support

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a project which needs to support Python 3.7, but I would like to use [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol), which was added in 3.8. To support 3.7, I have a minor bit of fallback code which just uses `object`:

```py
import typing

_Protocol = getattr(typing, 'Protocol', object)

class Foo(_Protocol):
    def bar(self) -> int:
        pass
```

This all functions as I would expect. The issue is, when running MyPy, I get the following error:

```
test.py:5: error: Variable "test._Protocol" is not valid as a type
test.py:5: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
test.py:5: error: Invalid base class "_Protocol"
```

The linked ["Variables vs type aliases"](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases) section in that error message indicates that I should annotate `_Protocol` with `: typing.Type[object]` (which does not work) or use `typing.TypeAlias` (which isn't available until Python 3.9).

How can I indicate to MyPy that `_Protocol` is valid as a type?

---

Another workaround I tried was in ["Python version and system platform checks"](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#version-and-platform-checks):

```py
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    _Protocol = typing.Protocol
else:
    _Protocol = object
```

However, this ends with the same error.

Comment: MyPy is not going to understand `_Protocol = getattr(typing, 'Protocol', object)`

Comment: You can try using `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING: _Protocol = typing.Protocol`

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/)? It is maintained by core team and is used to 1) backport newer types and 2) add some new types before they can be merged to `typing`. Your last attempt works after small modification: [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=671ce462d6200b14133afb24ef8c9235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that MyPy can properly understand `Protocol` as part of an import statement:

```py
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from typing import Protocol as _Protocol
else:
    _Protocol = object

class Foo(_Protocol):
    def bar(self) -> int: ...
```

MyPy will still flag *usage* of `Foo` as a type specification in Python 3.7, so you need a similar workaround for using it:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    _Foo = Foo
else:
    _Foo = typing.Any

def bar(x: _Foo):
    pass
```

It's worth noting that MyPy does *not* understand more clever things like `_Foo = Foo if sys.version_info >= (3, 8) else typing.Any` -- you have to use the simple format.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`typing_extensions`**](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions) and `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` to import `typing_extensions` only when type-checking the code.

```py
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing_extensions import Protocol
else:
    Protocol = object


class Foo(Protocol):
    def bar(self) -> int:
        ...
```

---

**typing_extensions** [checks](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/typing_extensions/src/typing_extensions.py#L384) the Python version and uses `typing.Protocol` for versions `>=3.8`:

```py
# 3.8+
if hasattr(typing, 'Protocol'):
    Protocol = typing.Protocol
# 3.7
else:
    ...
```

Comment: One nice thing is that `typing_extensions` does not need to be added as a regular runtime dependency since the import is only done when the type checker runs.

Comment: What's the point of `Protocol = object`, is this just to negate the need for using the `typing_extentions` dependency at runtime?

Comment: `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` is false at runtime, thus without `Protocol = object`, the `Protocol` would be undefined in runtime: `NameError: name 'Protocol' is not defined`. Remove the else clause and try it yourself.